# Общий шрифт для TextView

Tags: android, java, textview

Есть дизайн 1536x2048, там есть картинка, а в картинке - текст. Размер шрифта 36px. Можно ли использовать sp или dp, чтобы она на всех экранах отображалась так же? И чему будет равна 36px?

Answer (score 1):

Наверно уже поздно, но отвечу. Вот тут вы найдете ответ:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/materialy/pamjatka/40-edinitsy-izmerenija-chem-otlichaetsja-dp-dip-ot-px-screen-density

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.